# Como armazenar numa variável o valor do campo retornado com o comando "insert"?

Tags: firebird, firebird-2.5

Tenho uma **Procedure** que realiza os "inserts" e "updates" nas tabelas. A necessidade de criá-la foi para tentar centralizar todas as funções de verificação antes de inserir ou atualizar registros. Hoje surgiu a necessidade de retornar o valor do campo "ID" da tabela para que minha aplicação possa localizar o registro e executar outros procedimentos.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER procedure sp_insupd (
    iaction varchar(3),
    iusuario varchar(20),
    iip varchar(15),
    imodulo varchar(30),
    ifieldsvalues varchar(2000),
    iwhere varchar(1000),
    idesclogs varchar(200))
returns (
    oid integer)
as
declare variable vdesc varchar(10000);
begin
  if (iaction = 'ins') then
  begin
    vdesc = idesclogs;

    /*** o erro está na linha abaixo ***/
    execute statement 'insert into '||:imodulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues||' returning ID into '||:oid||';';
  end else
  if (iaction = 'upd') then
  begin
    execute statement 'select '||:idesclogs||' from '||:imodulo||' where '||:iwhere into :vdesc;

    execute statement 'execute procedure SP_CREATE_AUDIT('''||:imodulo||''');';

    execute statement 'update '||:imodulo||' set '||:ifieldsvalues||' where '||:iwhere||';';
  end

  insert into LOGS(USUARIO, IP, MODULO, TIPO, DESCRICAO) values (
  :iusuario, :iip, :imodulo, (case :iaction when 'ins' then 1 when 'upd' then 2 end), :vdesc);
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

O erro na linha mencionada está ocorrendo por erro de sintaxe. A **Procedure** é compilada normalmente, ou seja, o erro não acontece na compilação, pois a linha em questão é executada através do "execute statement". Quando não havia necessidade de retornar o valor do campo "ID", a **Procedure** funcionava normalmente com a linha desta maneira:

```
...
execute statement 'insert into '||:imodulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues||';';
...
```

Qual seria a forma correta para que o valor do campo "ID" fosse armazenado na variável "OID"?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi publicar a mesma pergunta no **Stack Overflow** versão em inglês por estar com muita urgência numa solução. Obtive uma resposta e resolvi postar aqui para caso possa ajudar alguém futuramente.

A linha mencionada no código que estava causando erro, foi substituída pela seguinte...

```
execute statement 'insert into '||:modulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues||' returning ID' into :OID;
```

[Link da pergunta no **Stack Overflow** versão em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312189/how-to-return-values-from-dynamically-generated-insert-command)